# Can I use WSGI with a URI that has spaces?

Tags: python, wsgi, spaces

I wrote a small WSGI App:

```
def foo(environ, start_response):
        bar = 'Your request is %s' % environ['PATH_INFO']
        status = '200 OK'
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                            ('Content-Length', str(len(bar)))]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [bar]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    server = make_server('localhost', 8000, foo)
    print "Running..."
    server.serve_forever()
```

And another script to test:

```
import urllib2
checkURL = 'http://localhost:8000/foo bar'

print urllib2.urlopen(checkURL).read()
```

I run script 1 (WSGI App). When run script 2, I has a problem here. WSGI doesn't retrieve request from script 2 (checkURL has a space between foo and bar) and all other request to my WSGI not responding.
Now, how do I correct this problem when url request has spaces?

Comment: Does using %20 instead of space not work also?

Comment: It works. But I need solve the problem when url request has spaces.

Comment: Can you give more examples on how other users make a call to your service?

Comment: I use WSGI App to handler all requests (parsing PATH_INFO and process) from client (Mobile and Web Client) and return XML. Sory, my code too long to post here.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking "Can I pass WSGI a URI with spaces?", so I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

The space character is excluded because significant spaces may
   disappear and insignificant spaces may be introduced when URI are
   transcribed or typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-
   processing programs.  Whitespace is also used to delimit URI in many
   contexts.

space       = `<US-ASCII coded character 20 hexadecimal>`

Bottom line.  No, you cannot use a space.  It is not a problem with the WSGI server.  It is a problem with your URI.

Further, you should not be using the WSGI server stand-alone.  You should be using it embedded in Apache via `mod_wsgi`.  When you do this, Apache will handle the illegal URI requests for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Typically a WSGI URI will look something like `localhost:8000/foo/bar/baz` or `localhost:8000/?foo=bar` and not use spaces, so I suspect that the server is timing out because it doesn't have built-in handling for spaces.

Maybe your question is really **"Can I use WSGI with a URI that has spaces?"** -- I think the answer is **No**, as @S.Lott explains that server's front-end should handle this for you; you shouldn't need to worry about spaces in your WSGI app.

---

*Original answer*

If replacing spaces is a fix (your reply to my comment seems like it is) , then you can use `urllib2.quote()` to replace the spaces in your URL with %20, like this:

```
checkURL = 'http://localhost:8000/%s' % urllib2.quote('foo bar')
```

Comment: but, if other programmers use spaces in url request, my system will not responding all other requests

Comment: I see, that wasn't clear initially. See my comment to your original question

Comment: Yes, it's exactly my problem. But some case string depend by users (I'm not at client)
Example: if some client request: http://localhost:8000/login?username=foo bar&password=b7a6f237e110de5786aea5024d7d0552

Comment: The answer isn't maybe.  It's "no".  If you use Apache as a front-end for wsgi (via mod_wsgi), Apache will handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I moved from wsgiref.simple_server to cherrypy and it work well. Client request will time out after about 1s. Thanks jcoon and S.Lott very much!

Answer (score -1):

You should use "%20" in URL's to encode spaces into then -- but don't do that manually:
use urllib.quote function, like:

> > > import urllib
> > >       base = "http://localhost:8000/"
> > >       path = urllib.quote("foo bar")
> > >       checkURL = base + path

(there is also the "unquote"  function for you to use serverside)